# Java Deployment Toolkit - When will installs be inline?

Tags: java, deployment

I'm trying to do some business before a user is magically redirected to download java, in the case where java can't do an inline install (and upgrade java WITH java). Is there any way to tell what deployJava.js will end up doing? I need to handle significant business logic before the user is redirected, and the documentation is scarce as to how one would go about doing this.

Help?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Can you rewrite it to clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user has java 1.4.2+, the install should be inline.